# Post data on slack channel

Tags: shell, slack, slack-api

I am using shell script to find the tps and error count in a single day using shell script and store the data in a txt file.
Now i want to use the same shell script to post data form that result file onto a slack group, but sometimes command gives bad request, sometimes Invalid Payload and sometimes it works.

```
curl -X -POST -H --silent --data-urlencode "payload={\"text\": \"$(cat <filepath>/filename.txt)\"}" "<slack url>"
```

Please help

Comment: Without more information to debug with, it'll be impossible to provide any help here.

Some information that would be useful

- Is there a pattern to when it fails?
- Can you show the exact strings being sent when it fails

Comment: Hi @ColmDoyle There was no pattern, sometimes it sends in one go sometimes in 10. I was simply sending a text file contents mentioned as    TPS for day <date> is : Min TPS: <value> <at time> Max Tps: <value> <at time> Average TPS: <value>. However this issue is now sorted, when i used -XPOST instaed of -X -POST.